# Draw cylinder from point X to point Y in Processing

Tags: java, 3d, processing, trigonometry

I have to points in 3D space that I want to draw a cylinder between. I currently have this code:

```
        applet.pushMatrix();
        applet.stroke(0);
        applet.fill(0);
        applet.line(this.start.x, this.start.y, this.start.z, this.end.x, this.end.y, this.end.z); //debug, shows where the cylinder should be
        applet.translate(this.start.x, this.start.y);
        applet.beginShape(PConstants.TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        float xdif = this.end.x - this.start.x;
        float ydif = this.end.y - this.start.y;
        float zdif = this.end.z - this.start.z;

        float rx = (float)Math.atan(ydif / xdif);
        float ry = (float)Math.atan(zdif / xdif);
        float rz = (float)Math.atan(zdif == 0 ? 0 : ydif / zdif);

        applet.rotateZ((float) (rx - Math.PI / 2));
        applet.rotateY((float) (ry - Math.PI / 2));
        applet.rotateX((float) (rz - Math.PI / 2));
        float r = 20;
        float len = HelperFunctions.distance(this.start, this.end) / 2;
        boolean w = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
            for (float j = 0; j < Math.PI * 2 + 0.2; j += 0.4) {
                w = !w;
                float z = (i + (w ? 0 : 1)) * len;
                float x = (float)(r * Math.cos(j));
                float y = (float)(r * Math.sin(j));
                applet.vertex(y, x, z);
            }
        }
        applet.endShape();
        applet.popMatrix();
```

The cylinder does draw correctly, however, it doesn't rotate correctly. I'm trying to use trig to determine the rotation angles, however, I'm not sure I've done it correctly. How would I get the correct angles to rotate around such that it is drawn from Vector start to Vector end?

Vector is a custom class with just a `float x, y, z`, and HelperFunctions.distance takes two Vectors and calculates the distance (pythagoras).

Thanks in advance.